# Display the WCF Service Reference endpoint URI that is in use at runtime

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I have created a WCF Service on my development PC with the address http://localhost:8090/TLA/TLA.svc

I've copied the dll, created a .svc file and hosted it on a local IIS box and can access the wsdl page via IE by going to http://myserver:8090/WCF/TLA.svc

I have created a test program to check that the service is working. This used the localhost reference when adding the service reference to the project.

I copied the test program to the IIS box and modified the .config file to point to the myserver address.

The test program can't connect to the service and I suspect it is because the URI is wrong.

How do I display, at runtime, which URI the test program is attempting to use? All the code examples I've seen are about changing the endpoint at runtime and use hard coded addresses but I want to know which one the program is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the **ClientBaseAddress** in your Binding object.